# How to add Custom text sizes as classes in CKEditor4?

Tags: typo3, ckeditor4.x

I am using CKEditor4 in TYPO3, and I want to customise the font size list to have my own preset sizes as classes instead of inline styles.

In my configuration Yaml file I have been trying variations on this:

```
fontSize_style: 
    - { name: "Small", element: "span", attributes: { class: "small"} }
    - { name: "Large", element: "span", attributes: { class: "large"} }
```

How can I make this work?

Secondly, if for example, I am applying the size to an `h1`, can I have the class be added to the h1 instead of using a span?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using the `fontSize_style` incorrectly. It should only have 1 entry to define the formatting:

```
fontSize_style: {element: 'span', attributes: { 'class': '#(size)' } }
```

This uses the variable `#(size)` to insert the class.

Then you just populate the dropdown list with the sizes you want:

```
fontSize_sizes: 'Small/small;Medium/medium;Large/large;'
```

Each size entry composing of **List Label** / **Class Name**

The second part of the question can only be done using the style dropdown as expained in the other answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it this way:

```
editor:
    stylesSet:
      - { name: "List", element: "table", attributes: { 'class': 'list' } }

#     Inline-Styles
      -  { name: "linker Rand", element: "p", attributes: { 'class': 'p-border-left' } }
      - { name: "Fettdruck", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'c-strong' }}
      - { name: "kein Zeilenumbruch", element: "th,tr,td", attributes: { 'class': 'nowrap' }}
```

> Secondly, if for example, I am applying the size to an h1, can I have
> the class be added to the h1 instead of using a span?

AFAIK that's not possible.

Comment: Actually, that is what I was already doing, but was hoping to instead use the font size drop down to declutter the style dropdown. Is it not possible to use the Font Size drop down for font size classes?

Comment: With this configuration the font size drop down is used. You use the expression 'fontSize_style' and I use 'stylesSet'.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest instead of using `fontSize_style` you can use `stylesSet` to apply it as an inline style of type span:

```yaml
editor:
  config:
    stylesSet:
      - { name: "Small text", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'small' } }
      - { name: "Large text", element: "span", attributes: { 'class': 'large' } }
```

*As mentioned, this would apply as an inline style. So the editor can choose only a group of words inside a paragraph, for example.*

If you want to apply classes to the complete format tags like headings `<h1>` `<h2>` `<h3>` or paragraphs `<p>` you can overwrite the existing or create new formats like this:

```yaml
editor:
  config:
    format_h2-large: { name: "H2 Heading Large", element: 'h2', attributes: { 'class': 'h2-large' } }
    format_h2: { name: "H2 Heading", element: 'h2', attributes: { 'class': 'h2' } }
```

Then you have to add new format variants to the `format_tags` as well:

```yaml
editor:
  config:
    format_tags: "h2;h2-large;h3;paragraph;pre"
```

*Notice the `h2-large` added here*

**⚠️ Important: It is needed to overwrite the default format (here `format_h2`) without initial classes as well, to ensure removing and reapplying those styles afterward works properly.**